# How to make a mutex in another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I want to create a thread in a loop, and when the thread is created, don't create it again until the thread is done. I use the code below, but it's not working, because the mutex will unlock while it's already unlocked. Can anyone tell me how to do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

int counter = 0;
std::mutex mtx;
std::thread t;

void test_mutex_t2()
{
 std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
 counter++;
}

void test_mutex_t1()
{
 while (1) {
   if (mtx.try_lock())
   {
     t = std::thread(test_mutex_t2);    
     mtx.unlock();
   }
 }
}

int main()
{
  test_mutex_t1();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `try_lock()` rather than `lock()` ?

Comment: What do you mean, *"the mutex will unlock while it's already unlocked"*

Comment: It sounds like you want exactly one thread running, is that right? If so, it seems much more straightforward to have a loop which creates the thread and then calls its `join` method at the end of the loop.

Comment: I just want to create a thread to do mass thing, like image recognition, but the main loop can not be blocked and when one thread has created, main loop could not 
create another thead. Thanks for your notice.

Comment: You could keep your thread running and just hand it a new batch of data whenever it completes its work? (lookup "producer consumer")

Comment: Yes， you are right. But I just want to do some C++ mutex and thread syntax test. It is so odd to me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Re, "when one thread has created, main loop could not create another thread." Sounds like what you want is a _[thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::thread` have to `detach` or `join`:

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::thread t;

void test_mutex_t2()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    counter++;
}

void test_mutex_t1()
{
    while (1) {
        if (mtx.try_lock())
        {
            t = std::thread(test_mutex_t2);
            t.detach();
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for answer. But I don't want to block the loop when thread is running!

Comment: In this case, how about using two mutexes? I have edited code accordingly

Comment: @emcute0319 What do you mean you "don't want to block the loop"? All the loop is doing is creating a thread, why do you care if it's blocked? Is it doing other work?

Comment: yes, this is just a little test.I am not familiar with C++.So I make testing it.

Comment: This is not a solution. There is a race condition. The main thread may unlock the mutex, the `try_lock` call may succeed, and another thread may be created all before the background thread acquires the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you actually want is to have exactly one background thread running at any time. If that's true, I would suggest getting rid of the locks entirely, opting instead to `join()` the thread before exiting the loop. Something like this:

```
while (true) {
    auto thr = std::thread(test_mutex_t2);
    thr.join(); // Will block until thread exits
}
```

However, I'd also like to point out that this means you'll have *exactly* one thread running. This raises the question, why are you using threads at all? You're spawning extra threads just to do synchronous work.

If you really do want multiple threads, you need a different synchronization primitive. Fundamentally, a mutex is designed to protect access to a single resource. What you want to do is *communicate* from the background thread to the main thread, notifying the main thread when the background thread has done something (finished, in this case). This is usually accomplished with a condition variable or a semaphore. The `std::condition_variable` class implements the first of these.

I would recommend passing the thread function a condition variable, which it uses to alert the main thread when it is finished. Something like this:

```
void thread_func(std::condition_variable* cv) {
     // do work
     cv->notify_one();
}

int main(void) {
     std::condition_variable cv;
     std::mutex lock;
     while (true) {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
         auto thr = std::thread(thread_func, &cv);
         cv.wait(lock); // Wait for background thread to notify us
         thr.join();
     }
}
```

Again, this is overkill for this simple example; I would use the `join()` method as above. But if you want have a more complicated communication pattern, where the main thread needs to wait at multiple places for the background thread, the condition variable is more appropriate.